# Implementation of getResources() Android

Tags: java, android, api, getresource

I have just started learning android programming and I came up with a doubt about the method getResources().
I noticed that when I create a Resources object all I have to do is:
`Resources res = getResources();`

The first doubt is the following why do I have to do in that way and I mustn't use the java keyword **new**? Shouldn't I do something like this:

`Resources res = new Resources();`

The second doubt is the following: at the top of my file I have imported the Resources class.

`import android.content.res.Resources;`

 Now I read the android api and it says that getResources() is a public abstract method, if it is abstract which class implements it? how can I simply call it typing getResources() if it is not declared as static?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your activity extends class [android.app.Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) which in turn extends class [android.content.Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) (three levels up the class hierarchy). Class `Context` declares the abstract method [getResources()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getResources%28%29) which means that your activity subclass inherits that method and you can call it from within your `onCreate()` method (for example).

The method `getResources()` is declared as abstract in class `Context` but one of the intermediate classes in the class hierarchy ([android.view.ContextThemeWrapper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper.html)) provides an implementation for the method.

Also that means that creating the `Resources` object is not your responsibility; it is done by the framework instead.

Comment: Hi @devconsole. I took a look to the ContextThemeWrapper.java source and I didn't find the implementation of the method `getResources()`. There is only overridden method `getResources()` which calls `super.getResources()`. Do you know about another class which implements `getResources()`? Thanks.

Comment: See also my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23933397/3343299) if you are interested please.

Comment: @janzoner The point is `ContextThemeWrapper` provides an implementation of `getResources()` which `Activity` inherits. That answers the original question. So what's wrong with my answer?

Comment: @janzoner And yes, it calls `super.getResources()` which calls ContextWrapper's implementation which in turn calls `mBase.getResources()`. I guess it ultimately leads to class `ContextImpl` but that is not a public class. It is an implementation detail of the SDK. See [source code at github](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/android-sdk-4.4.2_r1/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java#L611).

Comment: I am sorry, your answer is ok for the original question. I had my own question in my mind and your answer didn't provide me needed information. But as I said your answer is right. Sorry again. +1 for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

getResources is actually a method you can access from your Context.  So you can really think of this as:

```
context.getResources()
```

Your Activity class is your context in this case, which is why you can just call it with the syntax:

```
getResources()
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getResources%28%29

From those docs:

> Interface to global information about an application environment. This
>   is an abstract class whose implementation is provided by the Android
>   system. It allows access to application-specific resources and
>   classes, as well as up-calls for application-level operations such as
>   launching activities, broadcasting and receiving intents, etc.

Comment: Too late to edit. The answer was updated with that answer anyway. Thanks for the clarification!