# Where is the getResources() method implemented?

Tags: android

Does somebody know where is the `getResources()` method implemented? It is abstract method in `android.content.Context` class but I cannot find out which class implements it? I found an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16923169/3343299) here on SO but it seems it is not the right answer.

I am searching a particular class which implements `getResources()` method because I want to know what it exactly does.

Where can I find the implementation which "something does", not only calls something else?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implementation of getResources() Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16922890/implementation-of-getresources-android)

Comment: Why does it seem that it's not the right answer?

Comment: @323go The accepted answer to the question you mentioned seems to be incorrect.

Comment: Why? What makes you think it's incorrect?

Comment: @323go See my [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16923169/3343299) to the accepted answer please.

Comment: I do not understand the downvotes to my answer. It is implemented on `ContextThemeWrapper`. It does call `super` on the method, which takes you to `ContextWrapper` and its implementation. Which uses the `Context` that is passed in to the constructor.

Comment: @Emmanuel `ContextWrapper`s implementation is `return mBase.getResources();` and `mBase` is `Context`. It means there is called abstract method too.

Comment: `mBase` is a `Context` that is passed into the constructor. Some class, somewhere implemented all abstract methods of the `Context` class in order to be able to pass it in. Do not forget that `abstract` classes cannot be instantiated and that you can pass into the constructor anything that extends `Context`.

Comment: @Emmanuel I understand, but my question is where I can find the implementation which "something does", not only calls something else.

Comment: You will have to go through the docs and see what classes call `ContextWrapper`. I think you are getting confused. `Context` is `abstract` so you need to extend it to be able to instantiate that extended class (not `Context` itself). Since, your class `extends` `Context` you can still use a `Context` variable to refer to it. `Context` is guaranteed to have an implementation of `getResources()`. That is why you see a call like `mBaseContext.getResources()`. `mBaseContext` is a specific implementation of `Context` with has an implementation of `getResources()`.

Comment: It is the same as when you can use a `List` variable to refer to an `ArrayList`. The only downside is that `ArrayList` has some extra methods that `List` doesn't require you to implement, but since `ArrayList` confines to the `List` interface, it will provide implementations for the methods declared in `List`. So this syntax is completely valid when you do not need to use the methods provided by `ArrayList` because `List` is enough for your needs: `List list = new ArrayList();`. This is analogous to `Context context = this` if you are inside an `Activity` for example.

Comment: Add the relevant parts of the comments to your question.

Comment: are you referring to me @NiekHaarman? You mean answer? I had an answer but it was downvoted.

Comment: @Emmanuel I understand and know everything you posted, but question is clear - I am searching a particular class which implements `getResources()` method because I want to know what it exactly does.

Comment: @Emmanuel No, I'm sorry. I meant janzoner. Instead of asking us to read the comments, it is better to add relevant parts into the question itself to clarify it.

Comment: @janzoner Here you go [`ContextImpl`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ContextImpl`](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java) is the canonical `Context` implementation class. It has many ways for initializing its `mResources` member variable which can be then accessed with `getResources()`.

`Context`s following the usual `Activity` - `ContextThemeWrapper` - `ContextWrapper` inheritance path [delegate `getResources()` to the base context](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/content/ContextWrapper.java#87). The [base context is set up as `ContextImpl` instance when the activity is created](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/ActivityThread.java#2139).