# How abstract methods like getResources(),getPackageManager(), queryIntentActivities() etc. are implemented in android?

Tags: android

I was trying to extend the `PackageManager` class( I must have been thinking something at that time) when I found `queryIntentActivities()` is an abstract Method of `PackageManager` class.
I had used it as: `packageManagerInstance.queryIntentActivities();`

My Question is how did this method was implemented?

The same question can be asked for the implementation of `getPackageManager()` and  `getResources()`
there are many such abstract methods that you look through the API but can not find a proper implementation.

Traversing through the inheritence  hierarchy given in api i.e `Context`, `ContextWrapper`, `Activity` etc gave no proper implementation but such that it will lead back to abstract method.

I have seen [this question asking about getResources()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16922890/implementation-of-getresources-android) and the accepted answer does not satisfies my query.
A good point from that Qustion is 
***Context,hence some ,abstract classes's implementation is provided by the Android system***

But question is same.How implementation is provided such that it is invisible to api classes?

Comment: `"I was extending PackageManager"` may i ask what for? how do you want to instantiate your class?

Comment: and if you are curious: just try `String name = getPackageManager().getClass().getName(); Log.d(TAG, "class name: " + name);`

Comment: I thought I would change the implementation a little bit(just being curious), I would definitely give it a try..